# I have a list with string data type that contain formatted time(HH:MM) of a day but it also contain some unformatted time,in python

Tags: python, list

## i have a list with string data type items like

```
lst=['00:00', '01:45', '1:45', '001:59','23:46','32:00','09:75']
```

## but i want a list that contain only valid time and formatted(HH:MM) in new #list

```
lst1=['00:00','01:45','23:46']
>>>if (len(c0 !=5) or c0[:2]<'00' or c0[:2]>'23' or c0[-2:]<'00' or c0[-2:] >'59'))
#i'm trying something like this but able to do
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a function that verify an element in your list, then use `filter`.

**Note that it will accept elements with no leading-zeros (so '1:45' will be in the new list).**

```
import datetime as dt

lst = ['00:00', '01:45', '1:45', '001:59','23:46','32:00','09:75']

def time_verify(x):
    try:
        dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M')
        return x
    except:
        return None

print filter(time_verify, lst)
>> ['00:00', '01:45', '1:45', '23:46']
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you just want to match HH:MM and don't need to know if it is properly formatted time you can use regular expressions.

```
import re
lst1 = []
for x in lst:
   match = re.match("[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]", x)
   if match != None:
        lst1.append(match.string)
```

Take a look https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html at some additional examples of regular expressions